# mvcmusicstore v3.0 (storeDB does not exist in the current context)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, store

It's my first dealing with mvc and I am going with a tutorial from this link https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvcmusicstore . I have all steps done but when I write:

```
public ActionResult Index()    
{
    var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();
    return View(genres);
}
```

it says **storeDB** does not exist in the current context. Why am I getting this message?
Please help in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your context you have `DBSet<Genre> Genre` (not plural)

Within you controller you have - (Genres plural)

```
var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();
```

So you could change to -

```
var genres = storeDB.Genre.ToList();
```

Comment: Great happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this field declared in your controller?

```
MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();
```

Comment: yes 
     ((((((((   public class StoreController : Controller
        {
            musicStoreEntities storeDB = new musicStoreEntities();


        }   )))))))))  ..... and have no problem declaring it

Comment: You should have a file called MusicStoreEntities can you post?

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace mvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class musicStoreEntities : DbContext

    {
        public DbSet<album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genre { get; set; }
    }
        
}